# On the Banach-Mazur compactum, is the map $p \rightarrow (\Bbb R ^2,\| \cdot \|_p )$ a geodesic?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, geodesic

Let $Q(2)$ be the Banach-Mazur compactum of two-dimensional normed spaces (over the real numbers). Consider the map $\sigma : (0,+\infty) \rightarrow Q(2)$ defined by $\sigma(p) = (\Bbb R ^2,\| \cdot \|_p )$, is $\sigma$ geodesic? I don't even know how to calculate/approximate the distance between $(\Bbb R ^2,\| \cdot \|_p )$ and $(\Bbb R ^2,\| \cdot \|_q )$ for $p$ and $q$ $\ $ "close enough". Maybe I should start with weaker questions like "is this map continuous?".

Comment: Is it clear that the BM minimizer is actually the identity map?

Comment: Im not sure of what "BM minimizer" is

Comment: Banach Mazur (BM) distance is defined in terms of an inf over linear maps from $X$ to $Y.$ Which map (or sequence of maps, if need be) realizes that inf? For $L^p$ spaces the obvious map is the identity map, but "obvious" does not mean that it is really the one.

Comment: Ohh the identity map minimizes the inf ???

Comment: I don'r know, does it?

Comment: After an hour of calculation, Im unable to calculate $\| A \|_{p,q}$ for $A \in GL_2(\Bbb R)$